# How to use specific loaders for a specific file using webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a situation where I would like all stylus files to use the webpack loaders...

```
{
      test: /\.styl$/,
      loaders: ["to-string", "css", "stylus"]
},
```

but on global style files (ones ending in `.global.styl`), I would like to use a different set of loaders...

```
loaders: ["style", "css", "stylus"]
```

I tried the following...

```
 {
      test: /.*(?<!global)\.styl$/,
      loaders: ["to-string", "css", "stylus"]
 },
```

But it didn't work...

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.*(?<!global)\.styl$/: Invalid group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with not a **^** as follow:

```
// First case: someFiles.styl ending with .style
{
      test: /.*[^\.global]\.styl$/,
      loaders: ["to-string", "css", "stylus"]
},
// Second case: someFiles.global.styl ending with .global.styl
{
      test: /.*[\.global]\.styl$/,
      loaders: ["different", "loaders", "stylus"]
},
```